# symfony form collection error bubbling not working as expected

Tags: php, symfony

I have 2 entities with form types : 
User2Type.php is a sub form of Pca2Type.php.

If the form is not filled out properly, the errors from User2Type.php keep bubbling up to the "users" property of Pca2Type.php.
How can I get the errors so they appear next to their appropriate fields instead. I want the username, email, and password errors to appear next to their fields.

I will post the form types.

Pca2Type.php

```
namespace Homecare\HomecareBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class Pca2Type extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstName')
        ->add('lastName')
        ->add('umpi')
        ->add('agency', 'entity', array( 'class' => 'HomecareHomecareBundle:Agency', 'property' => 'agencyName', 'placeholder' => 'N/A' ) )
        ->add('create','submit', array(
            'label' => 'Create Pca'
        ) )
    ;

    $builder->add('users', 'collection', array('type' => new User4Type(), 'allow_add' => true, 'by_reference' => false, 'error_bubbling' => false ));
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Homecare\HomecareBundle\Entity\Pca',
        'validation_groups' => array( 'adminCreatePca' ),
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'homecare_homecarebundle_pca';
}
}
```

User2Type.php

```
namespace Homecare\HomecareBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Homecare\HomecareBundle\Entity\Recipient;
use Homecare\HomecareBundle\Entity\Pca;
use Homecare\HomecareBundle\Entity\User;

class User2Type extends AbstractType
{

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstName')
        ->add('lastName')
        ->add('username')
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('password', 'password')
        ->add('agency', 'entity', array( 'class' => 'HomecareHomecareBundle:Agency', 'property' => 'agencyName', 'placeholder' => 'N/A' ) )
        ->add('save','submit')
    ;


}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Homecare\HomecareBundle\Entity\User',
        'validation_groups' => array( 'adminCreateAdmin', 'adminCreateAgency' )
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'homecare_homecarebundle_user2';
}
}
```